# Using Lambda Properties - Compiler

Tags: c#

If someone can help me with an issue I just can't understand some of C# approaches to interfaces, etc. I've noticed on a few occasions that I can't actually access the class I'm in, when using the `=>` expression.

But, a simple long hand revision (commented below) fixes it easily. I'm not sure I see any difference... I've tried wrapping the line in `{ }` marks, etc. Could really use some wisdom - thanks!

```
public interface In1
{
         int MyProperty { get; }
         bool Check { get; }
}

class TestProp : In1
{
    public int MyProperty => if (Check) return 1; else return 0; //ERROR THE NAME CHECK DOES NOT EXIST IN THE CURRENT CONTEXT

    public bool Check => true;
    /* will compile
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { if (Check) return 1; else return 0; } 
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: `if` is not expression. It is statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

The key is that [expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) need an expression not a statement.

```
member => expression;
```

So the problem is your `if` statement. Try another approach like a ternary expression.

```
// use a ternary
public int MyProperty => Check ? 1 : 0;

// or a Lazy, if you want to emulate Scala
public int MyOtherProperty => 
    new Lazy<int>(() => { if (Check) return 1; else return 0; }).Value;
```

### Full Example

Here [it is as a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nFdSnI).

```
using System;

public interface In1
{
    int MyProperty { get; }

    bool Check { get; }
}

class TestProp : In1
{
    // use a ternary
    public int MyProperty => Check ? 1 : 0;

    // or a Lazy, if you want to emulate Scala
    public int MyOtherProperty => 
        new Lazy<int>(() => { if (Check) return 1; else return 0; }).Value;

    public bool Check => true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this also answers the other thing I didn't really understand (how to do multiple statements). Too bad I can't just wrap them in { } marks like scala

Comment: It would be nice if we could write expressions like this `{ var x = 1; var y = 2; return x+y; }`. Alas in C# we cannot.

Comment: There is kind of a way to emulate scala. Added it for the fun of it.

Answer (score 3):

That is called an [expression bodied member](https://davefancher.com/2014/08/25/c-6-0-expression-bodied-members/) (using the `=>`). It only accepts a single line. Your `if` `else` is invalid as it is multiple lines. Try instead

```
public int MyProperty => Check ? 1 : 0;
```

This uses the [ternary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) operator to make it a single statement.

The `get` works because it is enclosed in braces, no longer needing to be a single line. If you did `get => if (Check) return 1; else return 0;` You would get the same error.

Comment: "Line" suggests that it's got something to do with the textual representation - it hasn't. But `if` is a statement, not an expression, and *that's* why you can't use an expression-bodied member for it. The conditional ?: operator is an expression, *not* a statement, which is why it works.